# What tool is required to implement data transfer between PS and PL of Zynq 7000 SoC?

Tags: embedded, soc, zynq

I am new to embedded programming. I undetstand a little bit  what Vivado and Petalinux does. But I would like to how exactly I can use Vivado and Petalinux to perform data transfer between programmable logic (PL) and processing system (PS) through high performance port and using DMA in Zynq 7000 SoC?

Comment: The programmable logic is like a box of Lego bricks - you use the Vivado tools to configure the logic into something useful. Then you can consider using dma to transfer data between the two sides. This is a bit more than embedded programming in that you need to understand how to design digital logic. You could also look at Pynq for an easier onboarding to this environment.

Comment: The high-performance port is an AXI memory bus slave interface. Your DMA will be implemented as an AXI memory bus master in your PL. This is most commonly done using Xilinx IP blocks in the block diagram editor.

Comment: @Kartman Thank you so much for your comments, Do you have any reference or code or block diagram which will help me to perform the job?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you so much for your comments, Do you have any reference or (link) code or block diagram which will help me to perform the job?

Comment: @Kartman, thank you for the Pynq reference, I will  try to use it.

Comment: @Kartman, I could not figure out what to download for my board? Do I need to but some additional board? I have Zynq 7000 SoC. Is it same as MiniZed?

Comment: Do you have a dev board or just a chip? You really need a dev board to begin with. I somehow think you have underestimated the learning curve associated with this part. Why do you want to use this part and what do you want to use the dma for?

Comment: @Kartman I have a MiniZed board. I need to transfer data from PL to PS using DMA, to reduce the processor's load in transferring data. I assumed I could download Pynq for my MiniZed board but could not find it. I assumed that  only SD card image is required given a Zynq board. I do not need additional board? Is it true? So, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @Kartman DO you know how to resolve the following error in petalinux:    
Connection refused                                                                     
    while executing
"error $message"
    (procedure "connect" line 143)
    invoked from within
"connect -url TCP:127.0.0.1:3121"
    (file "/tmp/tmp.uxLFR9Q6w7" line 2)

Comment: Nope! I have no idea of what you are doing.